# how to solve the optimize for sequential key error in SQL server for unique

Tags: syntax-error

we were try to do on SQL14 but it was not working so we started with the SQL19 but then also there was the same error, we also tried it with azure database but that also didn't work. we are getting one one error in the whole sql procedure, we searched for that issue but we were told that it is not used in SQL server. We are stuck in this. So, I am requesting you all to help.

we tried to search on chat gpt, google and also from YouTube but not have any good idea. So, I am expecting to get an solution for the error

Comment: What's the error? Please provide a minimal reproducible example and the error itself.